# How to install Fedora on MacBook Pro 2016 without USB drive

Tags: mac, fedora

I already start Fedora on my Mac with a USB drive, but I need to use mouse there because touchpad and keyboard don't work. Unfortunately, I have only one USB Type-C to USB A adapter, so I can’t use the USB drive and mouse at the same time, so can I run this Fedora from my SSD not from usb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install Fedora using the [text mode installer.](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/25/html/Installation_Guide/sect-installation-text-mode.html)

Almost all distros still have some flavor of text mode installation.

Comment: Can I use graphics after this?

Comment: Yes.  The text mode installer is no different than the graphical one (except it only uses console mode).  I am not saying that this will solve your problem.. but it might and it is worth a shot ;)

Comment: may be it possible to run something like script that install drivers for the keyboard and touchpad during installing fedora?

Comment: [This](https://gist.github.com/roadrunner2/1289542a748d9a104e7baec6a92f9cd7) might help.  I guess the bottom line is that Fedora (or any other Linux) install just fine on any hardware other than Apple's.  You are trying to push a square peg through a round hole.  Apple doesn't want you doing this.